# Linux as a router: Sending ICMPv4 messages "net unreachable" and "host unreachable"

Tags: router, icmp

I want routers based on GNU/Linux to sent at least those ICMPv4 messages: `net unreachable`, `host unreachable`. Especially the host unrechable message is important to me: If a router resides in the same network as the destination host, but cannot resolve the IP, meaning it cannot reach the host itself, then the router should send a host unreachable message.

Currenly, I have to set up `iptables` rules. But I would like to send those messages as defined by [RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc792#page-5), meaning automatically: *If, according to the information in the gateway's routing tables, the network specified in the internet destination field of a datagram is unreachable, e.g., the distance to the network is infinity, the gateway may send a destination unreachable message to the internet source host of the datagram.  In addition, in some networks, the gateway may be able to determine if the internet destination host is unreachable.  Gateways in these networks may
send destination unreachable messages to the source host when the destination host is unreachable.* By the way, there are no routing protocols involved. Basically, each router is the gateway to up to three subnets.

What do I have to do?

Comment: Linux should do as you want by default. You don't have any default routes configured? If so, the linux system always assumes there's a route, i.e. via the default route, and then won't send ICMP net unreachable etc.

Comment: There are only static routes including default gateways.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, you keep editing your question and changing the scope. Although I'm not sure what you mean by:

> If a router resides in the same network as the destination host, but cannot resolve the IP, meaning it cannot reach the host itself, then the router should send a host unreachable message.

I have a hunch. If the router is on the same network segment, the destination can potentially be reached by definition. What you mean by "cannot resolve the IP" is also unclear.

However, if the destination host is down, the router will behave *exactly* in the way you described, as per the standard. So I am not sure what is it that you want that differs from the standard behavior ...

How your upper layer software acts on that response from the router is another story. But as per the standard you should get exactly the behavior you seem to be asking for.

---

#### Original answer

If you want to work around `iptables` (which I'm not sure from your question at all), then you'll have to set a [null route](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_route) (also [blackhole route](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_hole_(networking))). You'll likely want the former, though, as it will return the desired ICMP messages.

With `iptables` the trick is to use one of the values allowed for:

```
... -j REJECT --reject-with ...
```

Quoting the [HOWTO](http://www.netfilter.org/documentation/HOWTO//packet-filtering-HOWTO.txt):

```
 REJECT
    This module has the same effect as `DROP', except that the
    sender is sent an ICMP `port unreachable' error message.  Note
    that the ICMP error message is not sent if (see RFC 1122):


    o  The packet being filtered was an ICMP error message in the
       first place, or some unknown ICMP type.

    o  The packet being filtered was a non-head fragment.

    o  We've sent too many ICMP error messages to that destination
       recently (see /proc/sys/net/ipv4/icmp_ratelimit).

    REJECT also takes a `--reject-with' optional argument which
    alters the reply packet used: see the manual page.
```

Consequently in the [man page](http://ipset.netfilter.org/iptables-extensions.man.html) we get (search for "REJECT (IPv6-specific)" and "REJECT (IPv4-specific)"):

- IPv6: icmp6-no-route, no-route, icmp6-adm-prohibited, adm-prohibited, icmp6-addr-unreachable, addr-unreach, icmp6-port-unreachable or port-unreach (or tcp-reset)
- IPv4: icmp-net-unreachable, icmp-host-unreachable, icmp-port-unreachable, icmp-proto-unreachable, icmp-net-prohibited, icmp-host-prohibited or icmp-admin-prohibited (or tcp-reset)

For IPv4 you're looking for `icmp-net-unreachable` and `icmp-host-unreachable` respectively, according to your question.

Comment: Thank you for your input. This is my current setup. I would like a router to send unreachable messages whenever it receives an echo message for an IP address on a local network. For example, Host_01 -- 192.168.1.0 -- Router -- 192.168.2.0 -- Host_02: Host_01 sends an echo to 192.168.2.129, but Host_02 uses 192.168.2.130. Because Router cannot resolve a MAC address for 192.168.2.129, the router should reply with host unreachable. Ideally, I do not need to work with IP ranges in iptables.

Comment: @user2964971: please edit that into your question with appropriate formatting. Quite frankly I do not yet understand what your intention is - after this comment of yours. You never need to work with IP ranges in `iptables` if your kernel support [IP sets](http://ipset.netfilter.org/). Also: I gave two alternatives so *which* of those corresponds to your current setup?

Comment: Added *Especially the host unrechable message is important to me: If a router resides in the same network as the destination host, but cannot resolve the IP, meaning it cannot reach the host itself, then the router should send a host unreachable message.* to the question.

Comment: *If the router is on the same network segment, the destination can potentially be reached by definition. What you mean by "cannot resolve the IP" is also unclear.* The router sends an ARP request, but does not get a reply. Resolving as in L3 to L2 address resolution.

Comment: An exemplary topology: Host_01 -- 192.168.1.0 -- Router -- 192.168.2.0 -- Host_02: Host_01 sends an echo to 192.168.2.129, but Host_02 uses 192.168.2.130. In that case, I want Router to reply with destination unreachable.